# Python: why do I get an error when I call geospark?

Tags: python

I get this error when I try to call a geospark module

`from geospark.register import GeoSparkRegistrator`

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geospark'
```

However if I do

```
pip install geospark
```

I get

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: geospark in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyspark in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from geospark) (2.4.5)
Requirement already satisfied: shapely in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from geospark) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: findspark in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from geospark) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from geospark) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: py4j==0.10.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pyspark->geospark) (0.10.7)
```

Comment: You might got multiple python versions installed. Easiest way to fix: Install using explicit python version: `/usr/local/lib/python3.6 -m pip install geospark`. Best way use virtualenvs!

Comment: Check if pip is executed for the same Python installation you use for running the code.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer good point. But it looks like `/usr/local/lib/python3.6` is the default python for OP when he uses `pip`. So (s)he should use the python, with which (s)he runs the script, to install the package.

Comment: No, my default python version is 3.7.3. How can I set a python version 3.6

Comment: @emax: My first comment is just partly right. Find out the Python3.7 interpreter and install the packages directly there! `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable)'`will show you the python3.7 interpreter path.

Comment: great it works now and I understood the problem.